# hibernate connection problem

Tags: hibernate, netbeans

I had set up hibernate plugin to NetBeans and can not connect to MySQL dbs - the code:

```
package client;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;
import java.util.*;

public class HiberTest {

  private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  private int id;

  public int getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  protected static void setUp() throws Exception {
      // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application
      sessionFactory = new Configuration()
              .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
              .buildSessionFactory();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    setUp();
    Session session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query q = session.createQuery("CREATE TABLE test(myInt int not null)");
        List resultList = q.list();
        System.out.println(resultList);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
  }

}
```

HibernateUtils.class

```
package client;

import org.hibernate.cfg.*;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class HibernateUtils {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

The errors:

```
May 22, 2011 12:40:33 PM org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
SEVERE: line 1:1: unexpected token: CREATE
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:31)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
        at client.HiberTest.main(HiberTest.java:36)
Java Result: 1
```

Please help me with this that is a drag for me to deal with hibernate.
After all cfg changes I desided to post cfg.xml and hbm.xml may be someone would suggest something here they are:
cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://myhost:3306/wwwgeeksearthcom_geeksearth_test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user_name</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">**********</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <!--<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTransactionFactory</property>-->
    <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="HiberTest" table="guests">
  <id name="id" column="g_id">
      <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the log already said that the `<class>` inside the mapping file `hibernate.hbm.xml` is not properly formatted because of the following error :

> The content of element type "class" is
>   incomplete, it must match
>   "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)"

This error message means that you violate some requirements of the `<class>` , for example:

- It can only contain the child elements listed inside the parenthese
- The * sign means that child element can occur zero or more times.
- The ? sign means that child element can occur zero or one time.
- Without any * and ? sign , that child element must be included and included only once (e.g. id )

You can refer to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_elements.asp) to know how to read the DTD elements syntax.

Comment: Now I am sure U may only glance at the XML files added above and tell me what is wrong with that. I will be really appreciate this. I have tried to fix this but... the error is still here

Comment: your xml should be validated .I think it is because of other errors . What is the error message this time?

Comment: I had reedited the errors in my question, take a look. Thanks for attention.

Comment: How about this? <id name="id" column="g_id"><generator class="native" /></id> . Can it pass that error?

Comment: Now another error report has given, I had updated it one more time in Q.

Comment: `field [id] not found on HiberTest` means that you should have a field called `id` in the class `HiberTest` . Add a `long id` in the `HiberTest` class and implement  its getter and setter

Comment: Yes, thank U, I've found out it too and fix these problems, and also I had changed some code and tags and updated my Q again - now there are already done, but still some mistake/error.

Comment: the parameter to the `createQuery()` is not the mysql syntax , it only allows the hibernate syntax called HQL. What do you want to do actually?I suggest you read this netbean tutorial : http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html . It shows you how to build a swing application to display data from  mysql using hibernate

Answer (score 0):

you should use on .xml file `check xml` and `validate xml` as this menu is availabe with netbeans just right click on xml and check